# Pug/Jade миксин с 2я уровнями вложенных блоков или миксинов

Tags: jade, pug, blocks, mixins

Создаю миксин состоящий из нескольких блоков. При вызове миксина можно создать каждый блок, добавив содержание, либо не добавлять какой-то блок, написав block blockname с пустой строкой после.

Проблема в том, что содержание добавляется не отдельно в каждый блок, а копируется вместе в каждый из блоков. Пробовал называть и внутренние блооки - но так вообще не пишет.

```
mixin b-block(header, year, cname)
    .div(class='#{year} #{header}__#{year}')
        block b-block
            block header
                .header
                    block
            block year
                .year
                    block
            block content
                .cname
                    block
```

вызов с другого файла .jade:

```
include ../b-block

mixin c1()
    div.content
        +b-block('parentclass', '1907', 'm33')
            append header
                |title----header11111
            block year
            append content
                +maincontent('d1')
                h1 image: HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH1_....
```

или вариант с миксинами:

```
mixin b-block(header, year, cname)
    .div(class='#{year} #{header}__#{year}')
        block b-block
            mixin header()
                .header
                    block header
            mixin year()
                .year
                    block year
            mixin content()
                .cname
                    block content
```

вызов с другого файла .jade:

```
include ../b-block

mixin c1()
    div.content
        +b-block('parentclass', '1907', 'm33')
            +header()
                |title-----header11111
            +content()
                +maincontent('d1')
                h1 image: HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH1_....
```

Comment: на сколько мне известно, миксин может принимать только один блок

Comment: @MedvedevDev Спасибо! да, похоже так. А можно добиться чего хочу, как-то заменив блоки на дополнительные миксины?

Answer (score 1):

pug/includes/b-block.pug

```
block header
  .header
block year
  .year
block content
  .cname
```

pug/mixins/b-block.pug

```
mixin b-block(header, year, cname)
  .div(class='#{year} #{header}__#{year}')
    include ../includes/b-block.pug
```

pug/mixins/c1.pug

```
include ../mixins/b-block

mixin c1()
  div.content
    +b-block('parentclass', '1907', 'm33')
        append header
            |title-----header11111
        block year
        append content
            +maincontent('d1')
            h1 image: HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH1_....
```

Comment: Спасибо. как вариан может, но в таком случае, в index.pug нельзя передать необходимые параметры, которые используются в b-block, затем - в с1...

Comment: Передумал, по идее тоже рабочий вариант

Comment: спасибо! уже нашел решение, только без миксинов и больше файлов с блоками...

Comment: Да собственно не за что, сам попутно почерпнул немного, так как сам с pug начал работать не так давно )